# Token Based Authentication in Asp.Net Core API with token from Azure AD gotten through ADAL

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, adal

I am developing an application using **Asp.net core 1.1** and **Angular 4**.

In just one solution I have my API and the Angular app. So I don't need to host them separately or enable cors. To make calls from the client I just pass "/mycontroler" in the http methods from angular.

One of the requirements of this app is to use **login with Azure AD**, but I couldn't find anything clear and uptodate that could help me implement this flow.

What I have so far is the login from the front end using **Adal**, I am able to receive the user info and the token. So, how can I now use this token in my api to limit access to resources?

What I have in my API startup code is this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
       !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
       !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
    {
      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
      await next();
    }
  });
  app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
  {
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = 500; // or another Status accordingly to Exception Type
      context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

      var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
      if (error != null)
      {
        var ex = error.Error;

        await context.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message, Encoding.UTF8);
      }
    });
  });

  app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
  {
    Authority = $"{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"]}{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"]}",
    Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    TokenValidationParameters =
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
              ValidIssuer =
                $"{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"]}{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"]}/v2.0"
            }
  });

  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();

}
```

}
}

but I don't know exactly what to do in my controllers to check user permissions and other informations like the groups they are in.

In most scenarios I found is the token being issued inthe API itself using Identity, but my case is different, since the token is **issued by AAD**.

I have read many articles and posts here but couldn't find anything to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use roles based access control in cloud applications using Azure AD .In RBAC, a role is a collections of permissions. Roles can be granted to users or collection of users (groups). Please read [this article](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) for tutorial and code sample .

To get user's groups ,you can use Azure AD group claims . To configure your application to receive group claims :

1. In your application page, click on "Manifest" to open the inline manifest editor.
2. Edit the manifest by locating the "groupMembershipClaims" setting, and setting its value to "All" (or to "SecurityGroup" if you are not interested in Distribution Lists).
3. Save the manifest.

After authorization in app , you could find the groups information present for current sign-in user . Please click [here](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/authorization-cloud-applications-using-ad-groups/) and [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/) for more details about Group Claims .

And of course, you could always call microsft graph api to get user's group information or app role information . See [List memberOf](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) operation using microsoft graph api .

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, Nan Yu! I actualy had figured it out tho, and was coming here to answer my own question, however, the articles you suplied are definetly gonna be usefull! There another problem, tho.. I am strill trying to figure out how to use custom roles in my application. I added two roles in the manifest file, but I didn't find out how to assign those roles to my groups using the new Azure Portal. When I go to the IAM section of my App, I don't see my custom roles in the roles list.

Comment: In azure portal ,navigate to your tenant by clicking on Active Directory in the left hand nav , click `Enterprise applications`-->select your application-->click `Users and groups` --> click `Add user` button to add a user who you want to assign role --> select a user and select a role you defined in manifest .